# Share a picture on facebook, not via URL

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

I have a website and I would like to share pictures to Facebook using a button.

I am confused about how the share of a picture really works, I have easily implemented the share of the picture via URL http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[URL]&title=[title] and this requires my picture to be hosted on my server.
But I am wondering what other options are available?

Is it possible to share a picture directly on Facebook (like if the user was uploading it on Facebook itself)? I have heard about oAuth but I don't understand if this is using 3rd party libraries or if it is part of the Facebook libraries?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the `/me/photos` endpoint to upload a picture, there is example code in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/

The user must be authorized with the `publish_actions` in order to make this work.

Here´s some more information about authorization/login:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/